# fill select tag with values from database

Tags: html, ajax, database, codeigniter, dom

I would like to fill the `option` tags of a `select` html tag with values coming from the DB. I would like this to happen if the user change the value of another `select` tag. I use php5 with CodeIgniter framework.

Comment: Bienvenue à Stack Overflow, Sayf Ed Bz! Veuillez prendre note que les questions doivent être posées ici en anglais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look for `AJAX` (returning `JSON` data) and `DOM` manipulation to add elements to the select tag.

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to ease AJAX calls, manipulate the DOM and catch events.

Comment: how i can use ajax in this problem?? i mean in mvc

Comment: You can make a route in Codeigniter which returns JSON and then call this route in AJAX in the view (include jQuery and a script tag in your view)